# AWS VPN tunnel established and able to ping against each other, but curl doesn't work

Tags: amazon-vpc, ipsec, aws-vpn, libreswan, aws-site-to-site

I'm trying to connect local machine to AWS VPC using site-to-site VPN.
I've used ipsec protocol using libreswan, and succeeded to establish tunnel.(Confirmed at aws console that tunnel status is 'UP').

I was also bled to ping to each other, but not possible to execute curl command. (it hung for a while and got timed-out.)

Do I need to do any other steps? Or any way to debug this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

May be so that the ping and the curl command use different ports. If so you should set up routes for the curl commands. Standard ports for curl is 80/443.

AWS docs for route tables for VPC:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Route_Tables.html

Comment: Where should I look at to set up 80/443 ports? I already open firewall for receiver side.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Your VPC has a Route table (or more) that tells the traffic of what kind to go where. This RT needs to have routes saying that 80/443 traffic should go over the VPN con for all destinations or just the destination you want to reach. I dont think you want all 80/443 traffic to go over the VPN con.